# Recursively traverse directory structure on condition

Tags: java, file, file-io, nio

I almost never worked with files in Java and now trying to find a solution for traversing directory structures.

I have a structure like this: `\uploaded\abc\Uncle Bob\Another Dir\Hello-123`.
Here the `Hello-123` contains any kind of files and may contain more sub-directories.

Now the start path for this `\uploaded\abc\` from where I would start the walk. After this there is always 2 more directories, probably all the time, so that would be the maximum depth to walk in (after 'Another Dir').

**GOAL**: Find a directory that matches the input and upload all the files only in that directory (or sub directories).

**Example**: Given input **Hello-123** I want walk through all directories starting from the start path (maybe allow only depth +2 beyond that?) and do something with all the files in that directory (if found), after every file is processed then terminate the process.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've simply tried implementing my own Visitor by extending `SimpleFileVisitor`, yet I am not sure how to move forward and achieve the flow I need. I can't really figure out if I can achieve the directory logic only in the `preVisitDirectory` or I have to look for something else.

Comment: Just use the File class.  You should be able to do everything with that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework so I'm going to answer with advice rather than code.

Traversing file or other tree structures is a recursive process.

First of all you want to think about how you can write a recursive method. The thing that you are going to act on is a directory, so the method probably wants this passed to it as a parameter. You also need to think about the return type. Will the recursive method simply *find* and return the `Hello-123` directory, or will it take action itself - ie where do you want the code responsible for the *"do something"*.

Next you need to consider your base cases; when will your method decide whether to take any action or whether to call itself.

Your base cases look to me like;

- found the directory you are looking for (`Hello-123`)
- reached allowable depth (you mentioned allowing a depth of 2 below the starting directory)
- reached maximum depth (the directory has no sub-directories)

If any of these base cases are met you probably want to either return something back up the call stack or take some action. Have a careful think about what that thing you might return looks like. If none of these cases are met you probably want to figure out how to further recurse.